# How to fix : 'Padding is invalid and cannot be removed' error with rfc2898DeriveBytes and AES encryption?

Tags: vb.net, aes

I am trying to encrypt and decrypt text by using the rfc2898 Derive bytes method to generate an iv and key to use with AES encryption however I run in to padding is invalid and cannot be removed whenever I try to decrypt a text with the same password. This will be used to encrypt a text and sent to another user and they will use the same password to decrypt the text.

Here is the line of code where the error occurs:

```
plaintext = srDecrypt.ReadToEnd()
```

And here is the call stack:

```
Internal.Cryptography.UniversalCryptoDecryptor.DepadBlock(byte[], int, int)
    Internal.Cryptography.UniversalCryptoDecryptor.UncheckedTransformFinalBlock(byte[], int, int)
    Internal.Cryptography.UniversalCryptoTransform.TransformFinalBlock(byte[], int, int)
    System.Security.Cryptography.CryptoStream.ReadAsyncCore(byte[], int, int, System.Threading.CancellationToken, bool)
    System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(System.Threading.Tasks.Task)
    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(System.Threading.Tasks.Task)
    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter<TResult>.GetResult()
    System.Security.Cryptography.CryptoStream.Read(byte[], int, int)
    System.IO.StreamReader.ReadBuffer()
```

*edit
Here is the decrypt function

```
dim salt(8) as byte
  Function Decrypt(ByVal password As String, ByVal ciphertext As String)
        'variable to hold the string
        Dim plaintext As String = ""

        'creates the encrypted byte
        Dim encrypted() As Byte = Convert.FromBase64String(ciphertext)

        'fills the array with random values
        Using rngCsp As New RNGCryptoServiceProvider()
            rngCsp.GetBytes(salt)
        End Using

        'number of iterations to use
        Dim iterations As Integer = 1000

        'turns the password into a key
        Dim crypt As New Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, salt, iterations)

        Using aesencrypt As Aes = Aes.Create()

            'creates the key and the iv
            aesencrypt.Key = crypt.GetBytes(32)
            aesencrypt.IV = crypt.GetBytes(16)

            ' Create a decryptor to perform the stream transform.
            Dim decryptor As ICryptoTransform = aesencrypt.CreateDecryptor(aesencrypt.Key, aesencrypt.IV)

            ' Create the streams used for decryption.
            Using msDecrypt As New MemoryStream(encrypted)

                Using csDecrypt As New CryptoStream(msDecrypt, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read)

                    Using srDecrypt As New StreamReader(csDecrypt)
                        ' Read the decrypted bytes from the decrypting stream
                        ' and place them in a string.
                        plaintext = srDecrypt.ReadToEnd()
                        srDecrypt.Close()
                    End Using
                End Using
            End Using
        End Using
        Return plaintext
    End Function
```

The encrypt function is mostly the same but with the encrypt methods instead of the decrypt methods.

Comment: We can't help you without the full source code of your (minimal) example, so kindly edit your question and append the code, thanks.

Comment: The problem is likely to be on the side of the encryption, so don't forget to share that code as well. See [mre]

Comment: i have added the decrypt function

Comment: I notice that the code declares `Dim iterations As Integer = 1000` but doesn't use that variable.

Comment: For decryption, the salt of the encryption must be used. Currently you seem to use a randomly generated salt. Furthermore `salt` is currently not declared.

Comment: salt is declared as a global variable

Comment: If a different salt is used for decryption than for encryption, different keys/IVs are applied during encryption/decryption.

Comment: As @dratenik already mentioned, it would make sense if you would post the code for the encryption as well.

Comment: the problem has been solved @Topaco

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing the following lines as it causes the program to use different salts:

```
'fills the array with random values
        Using rngCsp As New RNGCryptoServiceProvider()
            rngCsp.GetBytes(salt)
        End Using
```

This allows the same salt to be used when encrypting and decrypting.